# Does this count as single threaded?

Tags: java, multithreading

For an assignment we have to show difference in time of execution between single thread and multithread. I was wondering if this counts as single thread, or if I actually have to call a new Thread object etc...

[image]

Comment: Actual source is generally preferred over a screenshot of source. Doesn't matter much here, but for the future... --- You don't have to "achieve" single threading, especially not via creating a new `Thread` object. It's *multithreading* that has to be "achieved".

Comment: The code you showed us is a single threaded Java application (assuming there are no hidden threads in the helper methods).  What task are you expected to execute using multiple threads?

Comment: Yeah I usually do post the source, just thought because of the question it wouldn't make much difference. Thanks though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok sweet. We are expected to execute the same task, but on multiple threads. So fill an array with the length of 5million with random numbers between 0-9, then count the number of times those numbers occur in the array.

Comment: This is potentially a bit of coding, because if multiple threads need access to this array, then you will have to coordinate it.  Also, you need a thread to stick around until the array is filled to tally up the duplicates.

Comment: Note that `(end - start)/1000000` is actually a long, so you will only get the whole number of milliseconds. You might want to use `(end - start)/1000000.0` or `(end - start)/1e6` instead to keep the precision you have.

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh right, cheers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you always have the main thread. Creating a new thread formally makes it multi-threaded (but for practical uses if the main thread only waits for the second thread to complete it can often be considered as single threaded).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class x {
    public static void main(String [] mainIsAThread) {
       system.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
//that is one thread
```